# OpenLayers/GeoServer/Oracle combo input/output scenario

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, oracle-dbms

Im completely new to GIS. I must finish already started project that uses Oracle as DB for geoobjects, Geoserver, OpenLayers. Task is to draw something on a map (OpenLayers must handle that drawing i assume...) and then save it to Oracle database(as a layer i think).

I have looked through some manuals on geoserver, but maybe you can help me to quickly start in this "simple" input/output scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OpenGeo Suite sounds like your best all in one solution

http://opengeo.org/products/suite/integration/

Though understanding the steps will help your build the web mapping application you want, here are some useful links that show you what can be achieved.

**Editing**

"OpenLayers provides vector editing capabilities previously only available on desktop clients completely in the browser, including snapping, splitting, and basic shared boundary editing backed by GeoServer and the WFS-T standard. With the OpenGeo Suite, make edits from the browser directly to an enterprise database all directly on top of Google Maps tiles."

There is a **New Openlayer Editing toolbar** available here.
https://github.com/geops/ole#readme

source code:
https://github.com/geops/ole

[image]

**Geoserver** works best with the a transactional Web Feature Service (WFS-T) allows creation, deletion, and updating of features. It can be setup with the additional Oracle Drivers to take data to and from oracle.
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/oracle.html

Openlayers WFS-T example - http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html